# UWP Color Foreground ListView Condition

Tags: listview, colors, uwp, textblock, foreground

I would like to know if it's possible to make a condition on a textblock in a ListView. I explain :

I have a models which contains some data and there is an "amount" in this models. If the amount is negative I would like to put the foreground in red, and if it's positive I would like to put the foreground in green.

```
 <TextBlock RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               FontWeight="Bold">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                        <Run Text="€" />
 </TextBlock>
```

This is the textblock, he is in a ListView.ItemTemplate.

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a converter. Create a class (e.g. `AmountColorConverter`) that derives from `IValueConverter`.

```cs
public object Convert(object value, ...)
{
    var val = (double)value;
    return val >= 0
        ? Colors.Green
        : Colors.Red;
}
```

Once implemented, create an instance of the converter in XAML and reference it in the binding:

```xml
<converter:AmountColorConverter x:Key="AmountColorConverter"/>
<TextBlock RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
           Foreground="{Binding Amount, Converter={StaticResource AmountColorConverter}}"
           FontWeight="Bold">
    <Run Text="{Binding Amount}" />
    <Run Text="€" />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your response, I did it but doesn't change the color of the foreground. I try in debug and the color returned is ok, but didn't change the color... so weird

Comment: @AnthonyNfr The [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run) class also has a `Foreground` property. Maybe the value applied by the converter to the `TextBlock` gets overwritten by the value of the `Run` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've already try it.
He my xaml code :

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Grid.Column="2"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Foreground="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ForegroundColorAmount}}"
           FontWeight="Medium">
               <Run Text="{Binding Amount}" Foreground="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ForegroundColorAmount}}" />
               <Run Text="€" />
```

And of course I used the using :

```
xmlns:converters="using:Sample.Converters"
```

And here my converter class :

```
    public class ForegroundColorAmount : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var val = (double)value;
        if (val >= 0)
        {
            return Colors.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            return Colors.Red;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thank's.

Anthony